# CSS calc not working in HTML table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create HTML table with last column wider then the others. I get the expected behavior using `padding-right`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td:last-child,
th:last-child {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
Expected behaviour using <i>padding-right</i>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now my question is how can I get the same behavior using CSS `calc`? 
Here is an example how I wanted to achieved it and [JSFiddle with both examples](https://jsfiddle.net/rpyydd5n/2/).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: calc((100% - 30px) / 4);
}
td:last-child,
th:last-child {
  width: calc((100% - 30px) / 4 + 30px);
}
```

```html
Hopefully the same behaviour as above using <i>calc</i>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 separate property lists for the td and th elements?

Comment: did you try flexbox solution?

Comment: @Bálint Copy paste. Fixed.

Comment: @markoffden I don't want other solution. I already made with `padding-right`. I want to understand why calc is not working.

Comment: I think the problem is with 100% in your calc function. You expect 100% to return the table's width, but is returning something else (maybe the tr's width).

Comment: You say this is the difference between using _calc_ or not, but the code examples show the difference between _padding_ and _width_ in table cells.